# Can I use a single XIB to create full-resolution interfaces for both iPhone and iPad?

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder

I want to load in an UISplitView an iPhone XIB, but it should be resized to full screen of the iPad... How can i do it? I dont want to convert the XIB itself!

I have read all the other solutions, but I do not want a second XIB, I just want to show it on both devices iPhone and iPad  in its specific size.

So if I load it on the iPad by using the UISplitView, it should be in the full size, and if I load it on the iPhone, it should only have the iPhone size.

Comment: From the class reference: Split view controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there's no such thing as a UISplitView.

From the documentation:

> The UISplitViewController class is a container view controller that manages the presentation of two side-by-side view controllers. You use this class to implement a master-detail interface, in which the left-side view controller presents a list of items and the right-side presents details of the selected item. Split view controllers are for use exclusively on iPad devices. Attempting to create one on other devices results in an exception.

So `UISplitViewController` is just a container. You just pass a master view controller and a detail view controller to it. The master view will be displayed in a popover controller in portrait orientation.

I think either I misunderstood you or your approach is wrong. The reason why this class is not supported on the iPhone is because it wouldn't make any sense. You can't just "resize the splitview" or whatever, you have to redesign your interface separately for the phone. It's difficult to give you any concrete suggestion without knowing what you're doing. Figure out what are you trying to achieve, have a design, make separate nibs for each device and try to reuse code and views as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Matt Gemmell wrote a SplitViewController that you can use as subview for the iPad (http://mattgemmell.com/2010/07/31/mgsplitviewcontroller-for-ipad/). You can check the source if you could use this for iPhone too. I found the source too heavy, I simply created an UITableView that loads other views when selecting a row (sort of a fake splitview).